# Is perl require statement necessary?

Tags: perl

```
require 5.00503;
```

The above perl statement demans the version 5.00503. I'm curious to know what would happen if the above statement is not included in a perl program.

Comment: Imagine you tried to run a script using new perl features on a machine with an older version of perl installed.  The script won't run, but the error will point to a code problem, not to an outdated perl installation.  This lets you know that the problem doesn't lie in the code itself, but rather that a newer version of perl is required to run the script.

Comment: [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) should answer your doubt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the version you specified is greater than the version of the Perl interpreter, an exception is raised.

So it's necessary when you use some features of Perl that demands the interpreter version greater than a certain version.

From [perldoc:require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html):

> `VERSION` may be either a numeric argument such as `5.006`, which will be compared to `$]` , or a literal of the form `v5.6.1`, which will be compared to `$^V` (aka `$PERL_VERSION`). An exception is raised if `VERSION` is greater than the version of the current Perl interpreter. Compare with `use`, which can do a similar check at compile time.